# common-lisp: difference between binding and symbol

Tags: binding, lisp, common-lisp, symbols

What's (in simple terms) the difference between setting a binding (LET) and symbols (=variables) in common lisp?

Comment: What do you mean by "...and symbols(=variables)"? Can you give us examples of expressions for the two concepts you're describing?

Answer (score 6):

Symbols and variables are two very different kinds of entities. Symbol is a name of something; variable is a container for a value. Variable can be named by a symbol.

Binding is an association between a symbol and a variable; when binding is in effect, you can refer to a variable by its name. `let` form creates such a binding.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear enough.
I was looking at this tutorial:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/First_steps/Beginner_tutorial

What's the difference between:
(let ((a 1)))
and
(setf a 1)

Comment: (let ((a 1)) ...) creates a variable (with local lexical scope), a binding between symbol A and this variable (in the lexical context inside the "let" for) and initializes it to 1.

(setf a 1) may behave differently: if there is a binding A, then it changes its value. If there is no binding, it creates a global binding A and initializes it to 1. However, the kind of global binding is left unspecified and differs between Lisp implementations (and their versions).

So if you have a variable named A, setf will change its value; otherwise the result is not fully specified.

Answer (score 1):

(let ((a 1))) sets the value of a to 1 until the point where the closing bracket which matches the opening bracket before the let is reached, at which point a reverts to whatever it's previous value was (or becomes undefined). You often see a let in the body of a function where you require local variables which need to go out of scope at the end of the function, so you would use a let there.

(setf a 1) sets a to 1 and assumes that either a has been previously defined (whether by defparameter, defvariable or let) or that a is a new special variable that needs a value.

It's a bit more complicated than that but I'm not sure i have the lisp chops to explain it.